# How to add autocomplete to text_format element?

Tags: 8

How can I add autocomplete functionality to a text_format field? I want to do this because I'm trying to create a field which has both autocomplete functionality (auto-suggesting certain configured entities) and an Input Filter on it to manipulate the same entities.

I have a custom widget for the field and have tried adding #autocomplete_route_name and #autocomplete_route_parameters to the formElement(), but since the text_format element is a RenderElement, not a FormElement, it seems like autocomplete cannot be added in this way. I've also looked into [Autocomplete Deluxe](https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe), which doesn't work for Text Format fields.

The code below works only for textarea, since the autocomplete states don't work with text_format, but I include it to show what I've tried.

```
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'text_textarea' widget.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "text_textarea",
 *   label = @Translation("Text area (multiple rows)"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "text_long"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class TextareaAutoWidget extends StringTextareaWidget {

  // ...

  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $main_widget = parent::formElement($items, $delta, $element, $form, $form_state);

    $element = $main_widget['value'];
    // $element['#type'] = 'textarea';
    $element['#type'] = 'text_format';
    $element['#format'] = $items[$delta]->format;
    $element['#base_type'] = $main_widget['value']['#type'];
    $element['#autocomplete_route_name'] = 'textarea_autocomplete.autocomplete';
    $element['#autocomplete_route_parameters'] = array('clue' => $this->getSetting('clue'));
    $element['#process'] = [
      [Textarea::class, 'processAutocomplete'],
    ];
    $element['#attached'] = [
      'library' => [
        'textarea_autocomplete/autocomplete'
      ],
    ];
    return ['value' => $element];
  }

  // ...

}
```